# How to authenticate a Google Cloud Build to invoke a Cloud Run service that requires authentication?

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build, google-api-nodejs-client

I have a NodeJS project for which I want to run some unit tests during a build at Google Cloud Build. Those unit tests require to send a request to a Cloud Run Service that requires authentication, so I need to supply a token with the request. To authenticate I use the npm library `google-auth-library` and use the following code to obtain the token:

```
const { GoogleAuth } = require('google-auth-library');

const auth = new GoogleAuth();
const targetAudience = new URL(url);
const client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(targetAudience);
const clientHeaders = await client.getRequestHeaders();
const token = clientHeaders['Authorization'];
```

When I run this locally I have Service Account Credentials JSON and set the location of that JSON file as `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` in the environment. But when running this unit test at Cloud Build, the service account file is not included, as it is not committed to the git repository, In my understanding this is not needed when it runs on Google Cloud, as it should authenticate with the associated service account that is specified by the Google Cloud Build trigger (which has by the way the role `Cloud Run Invoker`).

However, when I inspect the `client.idTokenProvider.email` locally I get the email of the service account, but at Cloud Build the value `default`.

This is my cloud build yaml:

```
steps:
# Install the Cloud SQL proxy
- id: proxy-install
  name: node:16
  entrypoint: sh
  args:
    - '-c'
    - 'wget  https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O /workspace/cloud_sql_proxy &&  chmod +x /workspace/cloud_sql_proxy'
  waitFor: ['-']
# Install npm packages
- id: npm-install
  name: node:16
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install', '--include=dev']
  waitFor: ['proxy-install']
# Run the tests
- id: npm-test
  name: node:16
  entrypoint: sh
  args: 
    - '-c'
    - '(/workspace/cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql -instances=[INSTANCE-NAME] & sleep 2) && (npm test)'
  env: 
    - 'NODE_ENV=production'
    - 'URL=[CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_URL]'
  waitFor: ['npm-install']
timeout: 600s
```

So how do I authenticate to a Cloud Run service when I submit a request during Cloud Build?

Comment: Edit your question and include your Cloud Build YAML.

Comment: You should find an answer in my article. I'm talking about a similar issue with Cloud Functions. In any case, Cloud Build built in identity is not really easy and consistent https://medium.com/google-cloud/service-account-credentials-api-a-solution-to-different-issues-dc7434037115

Comment: A side note: DON'T USE service account key file (JSON) when you can, it's a bad practice. My article can also help you with that.

Comment: @guillaume, I looked at your article before, but I could not find an equivalent of `AuthorizedSession` in the npm module. Is it possible to use the Service Account Credentials API with JavaScript instead of Python?

Comment: Hmmm, you can try something "new" (not really know, but it's pretty new in the client library. Be sure to have the latest version of the Google OAuth2 library). Perform a `gcloud auth application-default login --impersonate-service-account=XXXX`. Set the correct service account to impersonate, be sure to have (your account) the permission to generate token on the service account (role service account token creator), and use that credential in your local code. Java, Go and Python lib are compliant. I don't know for not, I'm not a node developer!

Comment: Thanks! By using impersonation and some changes to the javascript code I am able to authenticate from Cloud Build. I will write an answer with more details for everyone that is interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the hint of @guillaume blaquiere for using impersonation, it is possible to authenticate to Cloud Run from Cloud Build. On Cloud Build the build service account needs to have the role: `Service Account Token Creator`. You can then create an authenticated client by using JavaScript code:

```
const url = [CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_URL]
const scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
const auth = new GoogleAuth({
    scopes: scopes
});
const client = auth.getClient();

let targetClient = new Impersonated({
    sourceClient: client,
    targetPrincipal: [YOUR-SERVICE-ACCOUNT],
    lifetime: 30,
    delegates: [],
    targetScopes: [scopes]
});

const authClient = new IdTokenClient({
    targetAudience: url,
    idTokenProvider: targetClient
});
```

When you want to run this locally, make sure that your account has also the `Service Account Token Creator` role and run first the command:

```
gcloud auth application-default login --impersonate-service-account=XXXX
```